# How do I make my css moving image element compatible with smaller screens?

Tags: css, image, screen, translate

So I'm making an image that is moving down on page load. The problem is, that on smaller screens it does not show up. How can I fix that?

HTML

```
<img class="logo" src="images/Untitled-2.png" alt="">
```

CSS

```
.logo {
  position:relative;
  top: -160%;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  width: 50%;
  transition: 5s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 4000ms;
  -moz-transition-delay: 4000ms;
  -o-transition-delay: 4000ms;
  transition-delay: 4000ms;
}
```

Comment: Please put up a Stackoverflow snippet that shows the problem. There is not enough information in the code you have given to show the problem (what, for example, is the dimensioning of any container?).

Comment: And what changes the value of top so it can transition?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with `position:relative`.